# Random Variables with Standard Normal Distribution Falling into Specific Intervals

Tags: r, normal-distribution, probability-distribution

I'm working on a task where we look at 12 independent and identically distributed random variables - each of which have standard normal distribution.

From that I understand we have a mean of 0 and sd of 1.

We then have an interval of (-1.644, 1.644)

To find the probability of a single random variable landing in this interval I write:

```
(pnorm(1.644, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail=TRUE) - pnorm(-1.644, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail=TRUE))
```

Which returns the Probability of 0.8998238

I'm able to find the probability of **at least** one of the 12 random variables landing **outside** of the interval (-1.644, 1.644) with the following:

```
PROB_1 = 1-(0.8998238^12))
#PROB_1 = 0.7182333
```

However - How would if find the probability of **Exactly 2** random variables landing outside of the interval? I've attempted the following:

```
((12*11)/2)*((1-0.7182333)^2)*(0.7182333^10)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something here, and there is a much easier way to solve this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the binomial coefficient

```
prob=pnorm(1.644, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail=TRUE)-pnorm(-1.644, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail=TRUE)
dbinom(2, 12, 1-prob)

prob^10 * (1-prob)^2 * choose(12, 2)
```

0.2304877